# AWS ELB is sending the requests to all the healthy instances when configured to use TCP 443

Tags: amazon-web-services, postman, amazon-elb, amazon-route53

I have an AWS ELB which has two healthy EC2 instances. I am also using Route53 for DNS management. The EC2 machines are running Windows Server 2012 R2 and IIS 8.5. One each of the machines I have deployed an API. Also I have installed SSL certificate on the machines and selected the "Require SSL" option for the APIs in the IIS. I did that because I don`t want the ELB to handle the SSL termination.

My Listener is configured as follows:

```
Load Balancer Protocol: TCP  
Load Balancer Port:  443  
Instance Protocol: TCP  
Instance Port: 443
```

When I issue a request to my API using Postman for example, I receive response from one of the EC2 instances. However if I log on both machines and go to the IIS log directory (`C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1`), I can see that both machines logged the same request I issued at pretty much the same time (differs with couple of seconds). So it seems that the ELB routes the request to both machines instead of just one.

This was not the case when I was using the following listener configuration with the correct SSL certificate(which was uploaded):

```
Load Balancer Protocol: HTTPS  
Load Balancer Port:  443  
Instance Protocol: HTTP  
Instance Port: 80
```

In the second case when I issued the request, it was processed only on one of the machines.

But now having the TCP listener configuration it seems both machines are processing the same request, but I am getting the response only from one of them.
Do you know why this is happening? Is there a way to process the request only on one of the machines having this TCP listener in place?

Comment: Have you confirmed beyond a reasonable doubt that Postman didn't issue 2 requests (with or without your knowledge and consent)? How many times have you performed your experimental request and had it issued to 2 servers? Only once or is it consistent behaviour when executed?

Comment: Why do you not want to setup the SSL certificates on load balancers themselves?

Comment: @Matt Houser - Thanks for the reply. It seems this issue is related to PostMan I guess, because I tried invoking the API by pasting the link directly in the browser and the request was processed by one of the machines under the ELB. Then I created a small Console Application and issued a request to the API using RestSharp client and the result was the same - only one of the machines processed the request (I got a single record in the IIS logs on one of the EC2 instances). But when I try with PostMan (clicking Send only once) I got IIS log entries for the same request on both machines.

Comment: @hjpotter92 - Thanks for the reply. I want this to be handled by the IIS on the EC2 instances, because I do not want anyone who is not having the SSL certificate installed on their machines to be able to access the API. I am trying to restrict the access to the APIs. And still I want to have ELB with two EC2 instances to be able to handle more requests and easily promote changes without downtime.

Comment: @Matt Houser  - when using PostMan for issuing the requests I have the following results - calling the API 10 times using PostMan and all these 10 requests are captured in the IIS log files on both EC2 instances. As mentioned in the previous comment - this is not the case with other clients as web browser or rest sharp client.

Comment: When both instances are hit, are both requests GET, or is one a GET and one an OPTIONS?

Comment: @Matt Houser - both requests are logged in the IIS log files as GET. In the response I receive the details of the machine on which the request was executed. When PostMan return that the request was executed on EC2 instance 1, the IIS log on that machine states that the GET request has http status code 200. Respectively on the other machine(EC2 instance 2) is logged the same GET request, but the http status code is 500.